# How do you return in Jersey + Java an arraylist from a specific index

Tags: java, arraylist, jersey

It's 3 am as I am trying to crunch through this.

My ultimate goal is to get list of transactions occurred.

My GET:

```
       /*
   This GET method returns in a JSON format all transaction history of given customer id
   */
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("/history/{cId}")
   public Object history(@PathParam("cId") int customerId){
         return accountsService.getAllTransfersFromAccount(customerId);
   }
```

getAllTransfersFromAccount :

```
    /*
Gets the list of transactions of given customer 
*/
public Object getAllTransfersFromAccount(int cId) {
    for(Transactions history : transactionsHistory) {
        if(history.getTransactions() == cId) {
            return history;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And my transactions class

```
    public class Transactions {
    /**
     *  TRANS TYPE
     * 0 - Deposit
     * 1 - Withdrawal
     * 2 - Transfer
     * 3 - Transfer Receive
     */
    public int cId, amount, transType;
    public Transactions(int transType, int cId, int amount){
        this.transType = transType;
        this.cId = cId;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getTransactions(){
        return cId;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to print all transactions related to given cId? If I do a for loop it prints all transactions, just want to return certain one. 
Sorry for a bad formated question, 3 am writing isn't my thing.

Comment: *Gets the list of transactions of given customer* ...  should store it first in a **`List`**

Comment: What is transactionsHistory in your code?? In your code you are not returning a list but a single transaction.

Comment: To clarify I do make a list,     public static ArrayList<Transactions> transactionsHistory = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to print all transactions related to given cId?

What you are looking for is an `ArrayList`. You need to create a new `ArrayList` of `Transactions` and keep adding everything you want to that list.

You can then finally return this list to have those transactions which are related to given `cID`s.

**Code Snippet:**

```
public List<Transactions> getAllTransfersFromAccount(final int cId) {
    /* Create List */
    List<Transactions> transactionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Transactions history : transactionsHistory) {
        if(history.getTransactions() == cId) {
            /* Add Items */
            transactionsList.add(history);
        }
    }
    /* Return List */
    return transactionsList;
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks, **@nullpointer**. In Java 8 you can simply do:

```
public List<Transactions> getAllTransfersFromAccount(final int cId) {
    return transactionHistory.stream().filter(t -> t.getTransactions() == cId).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Or a java-8 version of it `return transactionHistory.stream().filter(t -> t.getTransactions() == cId).collect(Collectors.toList())`, without storing it in another variable

Comment: Hi, 
I did this but still not returning, just returns the variable type.
       /*
       This GET method returns in a JSON format all transaction history of given customer id
       */
       @GET
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       @Path("/history/{cId}")
       public Response history(@PathParam("cId") int customerId){
            List<Transactions> entity = accountsService.getAllTransfersFromAccount(customerId);
            return Response.ok().entity(entity).build();
       }